# I want to print on the same line but something isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing

This is an excerpt from a simple blackjack game that i am trying to make.

```
handpc= ['5H']

def carddisplaypc(cardview):
    print ('''
---------
|%s     |
|       |
|     %s|
---------
''' %  (cardview[0],cardview[0]),end='')

carddisplaypc(handpc)
carddisplaypc(handpc)
```

The thing is i wanted the 'cards' to be displayed side by side, but i wasn't able to do so nor i found anything that was useful to my specific problem.

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want something like this. I used a template that you can format it to any letter. The problem is that you have to split it tinto rows and then join them together.

```
def card(content):
    template = f'''
---------
| {content}     |
|       |
|     {content} |
---------
    '''
    return template

cards = [card(1), card('H')]
cards = [card.split('\n') for card in cards]

collector = ''

for card in zip(*cards):
    collector += ' '.join(card) + '\n'

print(collector)
```

result:

```
--------- ---------
| 1     | | H     |
|       | |       |
|     1 | |     H |
--------- ---------
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i think i uderstand what you did but like this i dont think i can print and updated hand without re-writing everything accordingly right?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are asking.. are you worried that it is not as function as you did in your example? You are right, I updated the answer so it is a function. For this I would prefer to use f-strings as the variable repeats and is local in the function.

Comment: @TESoblivionIV remember that you can use special characters to make a proper frame to the card ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: yes because i was thinking about running a for loop to print each card on the line, ill check tje special characters, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to draw it like you did with the first card:

```py
handpc= ['5H']

def carddisplaypc(cardview):
    print ('''
---------     ---------
|%s     |     |%s     |
|       |     |       |
|     %s|     |     %s|
---------     ---------
''' % (cardview[0],cardview[0],cardview[0],cardview[0]),end='')

carddisplaypc(handpc)
```

**Output**

```
---------     ---------
|5H     |     |5H     |
|       |     |       |
|     5H|     |     5H|
---------     ---------
```

Just be careful with the order of the `cardview` pointers. I believe it will be the top two strings followed by the bottom two strings. See example below.

```py
handpc= ['5H', 'KC']

def carddisplaypc(cardview):
    print ('''
---------     ---------
|%s     |     |%s     |
|       |     |       |
|     %s|     |     %s|
---------     ---------
''' % (cardview[0],cardview[1],cardview[0],cardview[1]),end='')

carddisplaypc(handpc)
```

**output v2**

```
---------     ---------
|5H     |     |KC     |
|       |     |       |
|     5H|     |     KC|
---------     ---------
```

https://ideone.com/TjAG7S

Updated with conditional statement:

```py
handpc= ['5h', 'Kc', 'Ad']
handsize = 3
def carddisplaypc(cardview, handsize_current):
    if handsize_current == 0:
        pass
    elif handsize_current == 1:
        print ('''
    --------- 
    |%s     | 
    |       | 
    |     %s| 
    --------- 
    ''' % (cardview[0],cardview[0]),end='')
    elif handsize_current == 2:
        print ('''
    ---------     ---------
    |%s     |     |%s     |
    |       |     |       |
    |     %s|     |     %s|
    ---------     ---------
    ''' % (cardview[0],cardview[1],cardview[0],cardview[1]),end='')
    elif handsize_current == 3:
        print ('''
    ---------     ---------     ---------   
    |%s     |     |%s     |     |%s     |
    |       |     |       |     |       |
    |     %s|     |     %s|     |     %s|
    ---------     ---------     ---------
    ''' % (cardview[0],cardview[1],cardview[2],cardview[0], cardview[1],cardview[2]),end='')

carddisplaypc(handpc, handsize)
```

**output v3**

```
    ---------     ---------     ---------   
    |5h     |     |Kc     |     |Ad     |
    |       |     |       |     |       |
    |     5h|     |     Kc|     |     Ad|
    ---------     ---------     ---------
```

https://ideone.com/4eTCd6

Comment: Thats a shame i tought i could store it in a function and just repeat it so it updates with the hand size, thanks anyways

Comment: You could make a conditional statement using hand size as an input, and draw that number of cards.

Comment: I updated the above code with what I was referring to. Hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: yes this would be my second option, i did it when i was doing hangman as well, thank you very much for your help